# Please help me identify this famous Classical Music melody

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

[image]

I sometimes have a piece of classical music stuck in my head and I just can't identify it.  I just downloaded a free composing software so I can transcribe what I hear in my head.  So please forgive any errors.  The notes should be correct, though the key is probably not.  For some reason, I hear cellos playing this melody, at least in parts.  I believe it is from a symphony by one of the masters.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: If it helps, this excerpt sounds like it's in A major. That should narrow things down some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tchaikovsky, Symphony No. 5 (op. 64), Movement 2, First theme.

Horn part, measures 8–17 (SOURCE: [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Symphony_No.5%2C_Op.64_(Tchaikovsky%2C_Pyotr)))

[image: Measures 8–10]
[image: Measures 11–17]

Comment: Thank you.  Funny thing, I was driving home from work tonight and heard it on the radio.  I had forgotten to check back to my question for a response until now, to see if anyone answered.